# Object's equals method

Tags: java, equals

I have created class `A`. And then I have created two objects of class `A`.

```
A a1=new A(5);
A a2=new A(5);
```

Then if i try to compare objects by using `equals` method, it return `false`.

```
if (a1.equals(a2)) // ->false
```

In same case, if I use wrapper class like

```
Integer i1=new Integer(5);
Integer i2=new Interger(5);

if (i1.equals(i2)) // ->returns true
```

Why? Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that you need to override `equals()` method for class `A`
If you do not override the method it will use the `Object` class equals method which checks whether the reference varaibles refer to the same object or not.

With `Integer` class, the `equals()` method is already overridden and which checks for the value.

Also, whenever you are overriding `equals()`, override `hashcode()` also

```
public class A {

    private int number;

    A(int number){
        this.number = number;
    }

    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + number;
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        A other = (A) obj;
        if (number != other.number)
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a1 = new A(5);
        A a2 = new A(5);

        System.out.println(a1.equals(a2));
    }


}
```

This prints out `true`.

> Why? Can anyone explain?

With `Integer` class, the `equals()` method is already overridden and which checks for the value.

[Integer#equals()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29)

A good tutorial helping understand the significance of equals method is provided on [theJavaGeek](http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/06/26/what-is-the-significance-of-equals-method-in-java/)

Answer (score 6):

You have to override the `equals()` method in your class `A`. By default it uses the implementation inherited from `Object` class , i.e. [Object#equals()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) which compares references, i.e. if both the objects are the same object residing in the heap , it returns `true` or else `false`. If you need to check for equality of contents of your objects override the `equals()` method in your class.

**Note:** It is generally a good practice to override [hashCode()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()) while overidding `equals()`.

I have provided a sample implementation :

```
class A {
 private int value ;
 A(int value) {
     this.value = value;
 }
 @Override
 public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if(obj==null || !(obj instanceof A)){
        return false;
    }
    return this.value==((A)obj).value; 
 }
 @Override
 public int hashCode() {
     return this.value;
 }
}
```

[Integer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) class already overrides this method , [Integer#equals()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#equals(java.lang.Object)).

> Compares this object to the specified object. The result is true if and only if the argument is not null and is an Integer object that contains the same int value as this object.

**Suggested Reading:**

1. [Overriding equals and hashCode in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java).
2. [Joshua Bloch - always override hashCode when you override equals](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&pg=PA45&lpg=PA45&dq=equals+and+hashcode+joshua+bloch&source=bl&ots=yYJkInp-VZ&sig=USfggouMdKPfsM6gR-HV5GatwU0&hl=en&sa=X&ei=RD72UeytLNSBhAeDh4HwCw&ved=0CFYQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=equals%20and%20hashcode%20joshua%20bloch&f=false)

Comment: I suggest also noting that, when overriding equals, it is very important to also override hashCode to ensure that two equal objects have the same hash code.

Answer (score 2):

When you have this,

```
 Integer i1=new Integer(5);
 Integer i2=new Interger(5);
 if(i1.equals(i2))
```

It will return `true`.

Because the `Integer` class overrides the `equals` method to compare vales rather than comparing references.

For wrapper class Integer, the literals from -128 to 127 are used from the same pool.

You will find this interesting taken from [HERE, see this for answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16890684/integer-literals-in-java):

```
    Integer i1 = 127;
    Integer i2 = 127;

    if(i1==i2){
        System.out.println("true"); //prints true
    }else{
        System.out.println("false");
    }

    Integer i3 = 128;
    Integer i4 = 128;

    if(i3==i4){
        System.out.println("true");
    }else{
        System.out.println("false"); //prints false
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should override equals() method for class A

for example

```
class A{
   int b;
   A(int b){
      this.b = b;
   }
   @Override
   public boolean equals(A a){
      return this.b ===a.b;      
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats because when you call `equals()` on `A` instance it calls equals of `Object` class, which **compares references**.

so if you will do:

```
instance1.equals(instance1); //will return true
```

To provide custom equals implementation you will have to **override equals method** in your class:

```
class A{


   @Override
   public boolean equals(Object obj){
      return equality;
   }

}
```